# How to calculate flight time and path length in Prolog

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

I have this database in prolog and i would like to calculate:

1) flightTime(Start, Destination, Time, Path) to compute the flight time for all possible paths.

2) pathLength(Path, Length) to compute the length of a given path (path will be a list).

3) shortestPath(Start, Destination) to print the shortest path between two airports.

```
flightPath(fco,jfk,10,4321).
flightPath(fco,sin,12,5671).
flightPath(sin,nrt,8,3467).
flightPath(lju,fco,4,2521).
flightPath(lju,cdg,9,8653).
flightPath(cdg,fco,3,1989).
flightPath(cdg,jfk,8,5461).
flightPath(cdg,lax,17,9321).
flightPath(jfk,lax,6,4141).
flightPath(lax,nrt,6,5743).
transferTime(fco,2).
transferTime(sin,1).
transferTime(lju,3).
transferTime(cdg,1).
transferTime(jfk,4).
transferTime(lax,4).
transferTime(nrt,1).
connection(X,Y) :- flightPath(X,Y,_,_);(flightPath(X,Z,_,_),connection(Z,Y)).
```

I managed to get the flightTime for direct flights and indirect flights with only one stop, but again I need all possible paths.

```
flightTime(X,Y,T,P) :-
  flightPath(X,Y,T,_),
  P = Y; (   flightPath(X,Z,T1,_), 
             flightPath(Z,Y,T2,_),
             transferTime(Z,T3),
             T is T1+T2+T3, P = Z
         ).
```

And for simplicity I made a graph showing all possible paths:

[image: flightPaths Graph]

Comment: The `;` operator has some side effects, it would be simpler to write two rules, one base case and one recursive case. What are the simplest paths you can reason about? Those should become the base case. Given a path `P` taking time `T`, how do you compute the time for a path `P1` with one stop more? This will be the recursive rule of the form `flightTime(F1,D1,P1,T2) :- ... , flightTime(F,D,P,T)`.

Comment: What do you mean shortest path in Question 3?? shortest path in terms the path with least time or least intermediate stations??

Comment: I would propose to look at `flightTime/4` only because it's the only one where Michel made an attempt to solve it. Moreover, mixing multiple questions leads to confusion.

Comment: @coder shortest path in terms of least intermediate stations. Sorry for not clearing this up.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Yeah I see what you mean. I'll try to implement it and will get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @lambda.xy.x I was not able to solve the two others, should I post them in a different question ?

Comment: I think it would be easier (you can also link the questions). In any case, you can only work on one problem at a time :-)

Comment: "shortest path in terms of least intermediate stations" is the first found  by a *breadth-first* search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
flightTime(X,Y,T,[Y]):- flightPath(X,Y,T,_).
flightTime(X,Y,T,[Z|TL]):- 
          flightPath(X,Z,T2,_), 
          transferTime(Z,T3), 
          flightTime(Z,Y,T1,TL), 
          T is T1+T2+T3 .

pathLength(Path, Lentgh):- length(Path,Lentgh).          

shortestPath(X,Y,P):-  once( (pathLength(P,_),flightTime(X,Y,_,P)) ).
```

For `flightTime/4` the solution is just a recursion in order to find all possible paths. Also `pathLength/2` is pretty forward nothing special.

Example:

```
?- flightTime(X,Y,T,L).
X = fco,
Y = jfk,
T = 10,
L = [jfk] ;
X = fco,
Y = sin,
T = 12,
L = [sin] ;
X = sin,
Y = nrt,
T = 8,
L = [nrt] ;
X = lju,
Y = fco,
T = 4,
L = [fco]
... and continues
```

Now to find shortest path there are many ways. The simplest-more obvious way would be to use something like:

> Store all paths -> Length encoding of paths -> sort by length ->
>   choose path with min length:

```
custom_length(L,Len-L):- length(L,Len). 
shortestPath2(X,Y,P):- 
   findall(P1,flightTime(X,Y,_,P1), L),
   maplist(custom_length,L,L1), 
   sort(L1,[_-P|_]).
```

Example:

```
?- shortestPath2(fco,nrt,P).
P = [sin, nrt].
```

Well it works but imagine that the list that `findall/3` will generate may be pretty large for large graph with multiple paths between two stations and then also sorting may be very time consuming...
The best practice here would be to let length generate smallest path length:

```
shortestPath(X,Y,P):-  once( (pathLength(P,_),flightTime(X,Y,_,P)) ).
```